# how to set dropdown values using ajax call in spring mvc

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, mongodb

I am beginner to ajax and spring mvc.I have got data from my database(mongodb) using ajax call.I want to know how to set dropdown values from ajax object.

```
 home.jsp

<select class="form-control" id="list1value">
<c:forEach items="${???}" var="item">
<option value="${item. pri-ID}">${item.uniID}</option>
</c:forEach>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript" >
     $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#id').on('change', function() {
               var value = $(this).val(); 
               $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "list",
                    data:  "id=" +value,
                    success: function(data) {
                         alert(data);
                         console.log(data); 
                         $('#list1value').val(data.cusID);
                         $('#list1value').val(data.uniID);
                    }
               });
          })
     })
</script>
```

my data object is 
    { 
    "cusID" : "14345",
    "uniID" : "123999",
    "Name"  : "wName",
    "pri-ID" : "11335"
     }

how to write code in  part to assign option values??

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, there is nothing wrong with your code. After assigning the values to list1value and list2value did you inspect the elements to check their "value" attribute?

Your code only changes the "value" attribute, not the text shown in the inner html of the element.

To make sure you can do:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "list",
        data:  "id=" +value,
        success: function(data) {
               alert(data);
               console.log(data); 
               $('#list1value').val(data.cusID);
               $('#list2value').val(data.uniID);

               //check if value is assigned correctly
               console.log($('#list1value').val());
               console.log($('#list2value').val());

               //Write in the inner html of the option
               $('#list1value').html(data.cusID);
               $('#list2value').html(data.uniID);
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following success callback:

```
function(data) {
    var selectEl = $('select.form-control');
    selectEl.children().remove();
    for (var key in data) {
        var optionEl = $('<option/>')
                .attr('value', data[key])
                .text(key);
        el.append(optionEl);
    }
}
```